# Coloring a variable in "read -p" command

Tags: linux, bash, command

I would like to color a variable in the "read -p" command. In another topic i found
a way to color the text string like this:

```
read -p $'\e[31mFoobar\e[0m: ' <= works
```

But if I put a variable instead of 'Foobar' the value is not shown because the single quotes are preventing the call of the variable $mmd.

```
read -p $'\e[31m $mmd \e[0m: ' <= doesnt ork
```

Do you know a way to make this work?

I tried:

```
read -p $'\e[31m $mmd \e[0m: ' <= doesnt work

read -p $"\e[31m $mmd \e[0m: " <= doesnt work
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can terminate and restart the escape sequence, thus moving the variable expansion outside, as per the following transcript:

```bash
pax:~> mmd="Enter something"
pax:~> read -p $'\e[31m'"${mmd}"$'\e[0m: '
Enter something: hello<enter>
pax:~> echo ${REPLY}
hello
```

Comment: There's no reason to export `mmd` here.

Comment: @chepner: that's correct, though not really relevant to the answer. I tend to usually export since I'm often calling sub-processes that rely on the environment. I'll remove it from this answer since, as you state, there's no reason for it.